# ListObject Range in SQL Statement

Tags: excel, vba, oledbconnection

I have a problem with an Excel Macro.
I am connecting via Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB to a workbook to extract data. In the code I wrote below I write in the SQL code to refer to the Range A1: B5 of the "Tables" sheet.
I would like to find a way to replace the static range A1:B5 with the dynamic range of a ListObject.

How can I do to insert the ListObjectRange inside an SQL statement?

Thanks for your help!!

```
Dim RS As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim conn As String
Dim SQL As String

conn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.Path & "/TEST.xlsx" & "; Jet OLEDB:Bypass ChoiceField Validation =True;Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1'"
SQL = "SELECT * FROM [Tables$A1:B5]" 'change with ListObjects("TAB_A").Range
```

Comment: `ListObjects("TAB_A").Range.Address` would return `$A$1:$B$5`, and you would need to concatenate that in with `&`.

Comment: Thanks a lot BigBen!
My problem is that the ListObject is in another WorkBook.
How can I get the Range.Address of a ListObject located in another WorkBook?

Comment: `Workbooks("otherworkbookname").Worksheets("sheetname").ListObjects....` Just qualify the workbook and worksheet.

Comment: But i guess that this works only if the WorkBook is open, right?... but what if the WorkBook containing the ListObject is closed? I use ACE.OLEDB just to not have to open the WorkBook :-(

Comment: Lol. Yes that would require the workbook to be open. There may be a workaround but not sure.

Comment: There must be a way to insert the Range reference of a ListObject into the SQL statement ... :-(

Comment: Call the list object by name `"SELECT * FROM [TAB_A]" `

Comment: Hi HackSlash! Thanks for reply. Already done but doesn’t work  